# Python DateTime minus TimeDelta vs TimeDelta minus DateTime

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, calculation

Say I have the datetime `now`:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 3, 1, 57, 3, 939862)

print(now)
2019-10-03 01:57:03.939862
```

and I have a timedelta for the start of business day (07:00:00).

```
start_biz_dt = datetime.timedelta(hours = 7)
```

I want to do a calculation that gives me the time from `now` to `start of business day`. 
ie, I want:

```
6:03:56.060138
```

But I obviously cannot do:

```
start_biz_dt - now
```

I could give `start_biz_dt` the same date as `now`, but I have many datetimes in a column of various dates, so this might not be the best way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find closest 07:00:00, so you can use next code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_of_business_day = datetime.now().replace(hour=7, minute=0, second=0)
if start_of_business_day < datetime.now():
    start_of_business_day += timedelta(days=1)
```

To calculate how much left just substitute current datetime from `start_of_business_day`:

```
sleep_time = start_of_business_day - datetime.now()
```